# iPad 3 not connecting to a cellular network at all

Tags: ipad, cellular-data

My iPad 3 doesn't want to connect to my cellular network. When i want to go onto the appstore or internet it says I'm not connected. We have taken it to our local iStore and to the network providers but it hasn't done anything, probably made it worse. We have turned it off and on, reset network settings and even changed networks. its second hand and we haven't used wifi on it yet. What could it be and what should we do?

Comment: Are you talking about WiFi or Cellular/3G here? If cellular/3G, does the SIM card work in another phone/iPad? What did the support staff in the Apple Store and the Network Provider shop try to do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Which iOS version is installed? Did it ever work since you bought it? Have you updated the iOS since you own the iPad?

Your description reminds me of my fahter's 2nd hand iPhone 3GS. He bought it and updated to the latest iOS 6.0.1 without knowing that the iPhone he bought was jailbroken. The update made the iPhone totally worthless because it could not connect to mobile network nor WLAN any more.